# Aplicação da função `assign` em loops

Tags: r, loop

Quero atribir nomes nas variáveis com um loop. Com `for` eu consigo:

```
library(tidyverse)

for(i in 1:6){
  names<-str_c('var',i)
  assign(names,runif(30,20,100))
}
```

Mas com `lapply` e `map` não:

`lapply`

```
lapply(1:6,function(i){
  names<-str_c('var',i)
  assign(names,runif(30,20,100))
})
```

`map`

```
map(1:6,function(i){
  names<-str_c('var',i)
  assign(names,runif(30,20,100))
})
```

Por que isso ocorre? Escrevo as mesmas funções dentro dos blocos, mas só em `for` a atribuição dos nomes é feita.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Isso acontece porque o `assign` modifica o ambiente pai. No caso do for, o ambiente pai é o próprio ambiente global. Por isso as variáveis aparecem para você.

No caso de uma função sendo chamada pelo `map` ou do `lapply`, o ambiente pai é o ambiente da própria função que está chamando, e esse ambiente é destruído logo após a execução da função.

---

Você pode ver o ambiente que a função está usando com a função `environment`:

```
> for(i in 1:6){
+   names<-str_c('var',i)
+   print(environment())
+   assign(names,runif(30,20,100))
+ }
<environment: R_GlobalEnv>
<environment: R_GlobalEnv>
<environment: R_GlobalEnv>
<environment: R_GlobalEnv>
<environment: R_GlobalEnv>
<environment: R_GlobalEnv>


> lapply(1:6,function(i){
+   names<-str_c('var',i)
+   print(environment())
+   assign(names,runif(30,20,100))
+ })
<environment: 0x14eec3a0>
<environment: 0x2bd9e368>
<environment: 0x13b43ae0>
<environment: 0xe7213c0>
<environment: 0x13dc00d8>
<environment: 0x1a7aab10>
```

Uma forma de modificar o `lapply` ou o `map` para funcionarem do jeito que você imagina é especificar o environment para a função `assign`:

```
lapply(1:6,function(i){
  names<-str_c('var_lapply_',i)
  assign(names,runif(30,20,100), envir = .GlobalEnv)
})
```

---

Nota: Se você está precisando usar `assign` provavelmente está fazendo um código que ficaria melhor se usasse uma lista nomeada.

Vale ler o capítulo sobre environments do Advanced R: https://adv-r.hadley.nz/environments.html

Comment: Como ficaria o código com `lapply` e `map`, então?

Answer (score 4):

O `assign` cria novas variáveis no `environment` da função anónima, não no `.GlobalEnv`. Para isso usa-se o argumento `envir`.

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(1234)
for(i in 1:6){
  names<-str_c('x',i)
  assign(names,runif(30, 20, 100))
}


set.seed(1234)
lapply(1:6, function(i){
  names <- str_c('y', i)
  assign(names, runif(30, 20, 100), envir = .GlobalEnv)
})

identical(x1, y1)
#[1] TRUE

set.seed(1234)
map(1:6, function(i){
  names <- str_c('z', i)
  assign(names, runif(30, 20, 100), envir = .GlobalEnv)
})

identical(x1, z1)
#[1] TRUE
```